# adding integers using shell script is not working?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

i have script file.

```
for file in *.TXT
do
    amount=$(less $file | grep BPR | awk -F'CACH' '{c=$1;sub(/[^0-9]*/,"",c);total+=c/100}END{printf "%.2f", total}')
     totalAmount=$(expr $totalAmount+$amount)
done
```

---

now my script look like this

```
for file in *.TXT
do
    amount=$(less $file | grep BPR | awk -F'CACH' '{c=$1;sub(/[^0-9]*/,"",c);total+=c/100}END{printf "%.2f", total}')
    echo "$totalAmount += $amount" | bc -l
done

echo $totalAmount
```

but when i run this it throw error at **$totalAmout+=$amount**.

i need to store the total amount in variable like totalAmount.

please help me

Comment: how about trying $totalAmout + $amount

Comment: I have tried this to brother. but its not working :(

Comment: PEBKAC: `$totalAmout` != `$totalAmount`

Comment: Why its this get minus voted. i know this is a simple thing. may not have standard. but its not working for me. i don't know who is just minus voted. but im asking you is there any mistake in the syntax, and y its not working. at least tell that :(

Comment: Why don't you just give awk all of the filenames and let it do all the work in one run? The `for` loop could go away, and the `grep` and the `less` are really unnecessary.

Comment: @Wumpus Q. Wumbley as i am new to shell scripting i don't know that. i just started working on shell script 1 day before :(

Comment: [Useless use of less](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html): Priceless.

Answer (score 1):

In bash (> 3.0?) you can do

```
(( totalAmount += amount ))
```

If it is not the problem of a typo, you can try replace your line of `totalAmount=$(expr $totalAmout+$amount)` to `(( totalAmount += amount ))`

If you are dealing with float numbers

```
totalAmount=`echo "$totalAmount + $amount" | bc -l`
```

Comment: You missed `$` in `$((expr))`.

Comment: not working. shows error as follows

((: 46691297.78: syntax error in expression (error token is ".78")

i am trying to add floating point values. is it because of that??

Comment: @Ricky `46691297.78` is not an integer, is it?

Comment: see my updated answer, you need to use a calculator , for example `bc`.

Comment: getting **(standard_in) 1: parse error**. i even copied the expression above

Comment: Please post your full script, for a simple code like `echo "$totalAmount += $amount" | bc -1`, I don't think you can get that error.

Comment: @John Smith i have already posted it. now i just change 4th line with your code

Comment: @Ricky, found the problem, now try it again.

Comment: No luck! and thank you all for your support. i found a solution
**totalRawAmount=$(echo "$amount"+"$totalRawAmount" | bc)** :)

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic operations more complex than integer additions can be performed with [`dc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc_%28computer_program%29) or [`bc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_programming_language) command line calculators.

`dc` is reverse polish notation whereas `bc` is more familiar.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `for` loop and `less` is redundant.

If you just need `totalAmount` and not using `amount` anywhere, you can get rid of loop and floating point summation.

```
totalAmount = $(grep BPR *.TXT | awk <awk_script>)
```

Further `grep` is also redundant if you let `awk` do the its job using `/BPR/`.

```
totalAmount=$(awk -F'CACH' '/BPR/ {c=$1;sub(/[^0-9]*/,"",c);total+=c/100}END{printf "%.2f", total}' *.TXT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Space is important, as `expr` is a command that processes its arguments.

```
expr $totalAmount+$amount
```

runs `expr` with a single argument (assuming no word-splitting results from the parameter expansion), while

```
expr $totalAmount + $amount
```

runs `expr` with 3 arguments (again, assuming no other word-splitting). The single argument variety would simply evaluate to the same string; it does not attempt to parse the argument as an addition.

Using `expr` for arithmetic is mostly obsolete, as the POSIX standard includes arithmetic expansion in the form of

```
totalAmount=$(( totalAmount + amount ))
```

Answer (score 0):

After removing the non-essential pieces, your script is equivalent to this:

```
totalAmount=$(awk -F'CACH' '
  /BPR/ {c=$1;sub(/[^0-9]*/,"",c);total+=c/100}
  END {printf "%.2f", total}' *.TXT)
```

Answer (score 0):

This got worked for me. :) ahh!! i spend more than 12 hrs behind this script.. :(

```
amount=0
ediAmount=0
totalRawAmount=0
totalEdiAmount=0

for file in *.TXT
do
    amount=$(less $file | grep BPR | awk -F'CACH' '{c=$1;sub(/[^0-9]*/,"",c);total+=c/100}END{printf "%.2f", total}')
    totalRawAmount=$(echo "$amount"+"$totalRawAmount" | bc)
done

echo $totalRawAmount
```